# GridGain Hbase Integration

Tags: hbase, gridgain

I have a usecase where I want to implement GridGain as processing grid and Hbase for data storage. According to GridGain API for V 4.3 it has a support for Hbase. 
http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc/org/gridgain/grid/cache/store/hbase/package-summary.html
I am not sure of pros and con for the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using HBase as a backing store is a viable approach when used with GridGain in-memory caching.

You can also take a look at GridGain Hadoop accelerator product which has 2 components In-Memory MapReduce and In-Memory File System (GGFS). Those 2 combined also provide near-real-time performance for distributed computations and data storage.

Comment: GridGain 5.2 has components  In memory DB in GdiGain HPC. Grid Gain architecture diagram shoes In memory DB can access SQL, No SQL db. Can this be used.